# How to use sticky behaviour with overflow hidden?

Tags: css, hidden, sticky

i'm setting all my divs to overflow: hidden as a default style and on a child div i'm using sticky, the problem is i'm not getting the sticky behaviour with overflow hidden.
**i want a solution without changing my default style .**

```
 <div class="container" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <!-- other content -->

  <div class="toc" style="position: sticky;">
    <!-- sticky div here -->
  </div>

  <!-- other content -->
</div>
```

Comment: If you are trying to use position: sticky and it is not working, it is because one of the elements wrapping it is using overflow with a value of hidden , auto or scroll. May be you can try with overflow: clip;

Comment: Sticky is `offset relative to its nearest scrolling ancestor` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: yes i know that, and i tried to use clip instead but seems like it's breaking some other style so i'm looking for an alternative to get the sticky behaviour or a solution instead